# YQL (Yahoo! Query Language) - Help with adding parameters

Tags: yql

I'm doing a very simple YQL statement:

```
select * from xml where url="http://www.wowhead.com/item=50278&xml"
```

The rest query looks like this (super long with crazy url escape codes):

```
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20xml%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wowhead.com%2Fitem%3D50278%26amp%3Bamp%3Bxml%22
```

So I'm trying to use the query alias to shorten it down. I know I can use something like url=@parameter but how would I do it so the item number is the variable and the rest query would look something like:

```
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql/RVCA18/wowheadXML?item=50278
```

I appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can build the URL to the XML file using a *URI Template* ([info](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-gregorio-uritemplate-03), YQL uses the 03 draft).  The YQL query to do that would look like the following.

```
select * from xml where url in (
    select url from uritemplate 
    where template="http://www.wowhead.com/item={item}&xml" and item=@item
);
```

<sup>([Try this in the YQL console](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?item=50278&q=select%20*%20from%20xml%20where%20url%20in%20(select%20url%20from%20uritemplate%20where%20template%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wowhead.com%2Fitem%3D%7Bitem%7D%26xml%22%20and%20item%3D%40item)%3B))</sup>

The next stage, which it looks like you already know how to do, is to alias the above query to `wowheadXML` and call it with the `item` value in the query string ([example](http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql/peter/wowheadXML?item=50278)).

Comment: Fantastic, this is exactly what I was looking for. I couldn't find this info in the online documentation. Thank you!